# Allow only letters, numbers and minus sign in input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

In my project there is a basic form where the user can input a value to search, I want to allow just letters, numbers and minus sign, all other chars and keys like ctrl/shift avoided.
Minus sign should not be at the beginning of the string

So, I think the best way is to use the keypress event, so I started the following code:

```
$('#input-field').on('keypress', function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
            
});
```

I'm using toUpperCase to capitalize all the letters.
Said that I'm confused about the best way to perform what I need.

Any help or hint?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your issue, you are trying to check the value entered "real time".

In the case, I will use input event to get value changed and following regex.

```
/^(?!\-)[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+$/
```

Details:

- `^(?!\-)`: Minus sign should not be at the beginning of the string
- `[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+$`: String only has letters, numbers and minus sign

```js
// Add error message element after input.
$('#input-search').after('<span class="error-message">Please write your message error here!</span>')

$('#input-search').on('input', function (evt) {
  var $regex=/^(?!\-)[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
  var value = evt.target.value;
  if (value.length === 0) {
    evt.target.className = ''
    return
  }
  
  var result = value.match($regex);
  
  if (result) {
    evt.target.className = 'valid'
  } else {
    evt.target.className = 'invalid'
  }
})
```

```css
input.invalid + .error-message {
  display: initial;
}

.error-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="input-search">Search:</label>
<input type="search" id="input-search">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect.